# Output printing initialized minimum value instead of printing updated one

Tags: java

Here is my code below, it should print the maximum temperature at a specific hour. It always ends up printing -1000 at 5.

```java
package javaPracticeNotes;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab3_7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int temp;
        int maxtemp = -1000;
        int timeAtMax = 0;
        int hour;

        for (hour = 1; hour <= 5; hour++) {

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the temperature at " + hour);
            temp = scan.nextInt();
            if (maxtemp < temp) {
                temp = maxtemp;
                timeAtMax = hour;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The max temperature of the day was " + maxtemp + " at" + timeAtMax);
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps update the code to set `maxtemp = temp` , currently  it not changing `maxtemp`

Comment: You are never updated the value of `maxtemp` (which is the variable you are printing out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement is right, just invert the `temp = maxtemp;`

```
if (maxtemp < temp) {
    maxtemp = temp;
    timeAtMax = hour;
}
```

Comment: ah, preciate it